# Create sequence of times for 32Hz in format hh:mm:ss

Tags: r, lubridate

I'd like to create a sequence of times from 00:00:00 to 00:38:24 separated by 1/32 seconds. This means many times will be repeated but it doesn't matter.

I've tried:

```
require(lubridate)

#Convert 00:38:24 to seconds
timeEnd<-period_to_seconds(hms("00:38:24"))
>timeEnd
[1] 2304

#Total number of elements in sequence 
timeEnd*32Hz=73728 elements

#Create a sequence from 0 to timeEnd in 1/32 steps
t<-seq(0,timeEnd,by=1/32) #This bit is wrong! makes 73729 elements

#Convert to 00:00:00 format
sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', seconds_to_period(t)@hour, minute(seconds_to_period(t)), second(seconds_to_period(t)))

>t[1:5]
[1] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
```

1. Is there a better solution?
2. There are the wrong number of elements in the sequence. It should be 73728 but I get 73729. Why?

Comment: 73729 elements is correct. E.g. the sequence from 0 to 2 with step = 1 is `c(0,1,2)` i.e. 3 elements not 2, because it includes also the initial zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a better solution; but using only base and stringi and using a function as a wrapper for a bit more flexibility. Time values can be passed as a character and time increments as a fraction or whatever.

```
f <- function(start_time = "00:00:00", end_time = "00:38:24",
              time_inc = 1/32, ...){

     options(digits.secs=4) 

    tl <- lapply(list(start_time, end_time), function(i){
           as.POSIXct(i, format = "%H:%M:%OS", tz = "EST")
          })

    as_seq <- seq(tl[[1]], tl[[2]], by = time_inc)

    stringi::stri_datetime_format(as_seq, format = "HH:mm:ss:SSSS")
}

time.seq <- f()

> head(time.seq)
[1] "00:00:00:0000" "00:00:00:0310" "00:00:00:0620" "00:00:00:0930" "00:00:00:1250" "00:00:00:1560"
> tail(time.seq)
[1] "00:38:23:8430" "00:38:23:8750" "00:38:23:9060" "00:38:23:9370" "00:38:23:9680" "00:38:24:0000"
```